# Based View Class - called success_url method but redirect doesn't seem to work

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am using a based view class to update an article in my app named **article**.
I am implementing it just like how **UpdateView** works however i can't seem to make it redirect it after validating the form. I called **success_url** method to redirect into the detail view, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

I set **get_absolute_url** in models,

```
#models.py

class Article(models.Model):
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:article-detail', kwargs={"id":  self.id})
```

and in urls

```
#urls.py
app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/edit/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article-edit'),
    path('<int:id>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]
```

and on views:

#views.py

```
class ArticleUpdateView(View):
    template_name = 'articles/article_edit.html'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        return reverse('articles:article-detail', kwargs={'id': id})
    
    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = None
        if id is not None:
            obj = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
            return obj
    
    def get(self, request, id=None,  *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            form = ArticleModelForm(instance=obj)
            context['article'] = obj
            context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj is not None:
            form = ArticleModelForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                context['article'] = obj
                context['form'] = form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I tried using it on UpdateView class and redirect seems to work fine, i'd like to use it on based view class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django base View class will not call something like `get_success_url()` automatically, that is something that is added in to the functionality of a generic class based view like `UpdateView` from another class that it inherits. If you want to redirect in a base View then you will need to actually put in a redirect call.

In your views.py file you can import `from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect` and then in your `if form.isvalid():` statement in your view you can add in the line `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`. Just calling `get_success_url()` does nothing on its own with how you have defined it because the `reverse()` shortcut just generates the url based on the name and arguments that you pass into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Chack this, first you need to import reverse_lazy

```
class ArticleUpdateView(UpdateView):
.....

    def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse_lazy('article-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: They are wanting to use the base `View` class, not the `UpdateView` class.

Comment: ok....................

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form you can proceed the redirection by setting a pull or get method for the form and set the action value to the url you want to redirect directly in your template in html. Here's an exemple :

```
<form id="contactForm" name="updateArticle" action="{% url 'article-detail' %}" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {% for field in form %}
           /* Your code */
       {% endfor %}
       <button type="submit">Update Post</button>
</form>
```

Then in your **ArticleDetailView** you can set your post() method to render the details page:

```
class ArticleDetailsView(View):
    template_name = 'articles/article_details.html'

    post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your code
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

You can also use the redirect() method instead of the render(). You can find the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class ArticleUpdateView(View, FormMixin):
    ...
```

`FormMixin` contains the magic you seek.